# Python SQLAlchemy get last entry (by timestamp) before given timestamp

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an SQLAlchemy query which looks like this:

```
def get_most_recent(session, model, **kwargs):
    """ Get a single element from the DB which has the most recent timstemp """
    all_records = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).order_by(model.timestamp).all()
```

The idea here is to get all entries filtered by `**kwargs` and then order by the `timestamp` field which all tables are expected to have. I can then get the last entry if it is not empty by returning `all_records[-1]` or else `None`.

I'd like to modify this to allow an option to only get entries which occurred before a specific date. The idea is something like this:

```
def get_most_recent(session, model, **kwargs):
    """ Get a single element from the DB which has the most recent timstemp """
    before_date = kwargs.pop('last_datetime', None)
    all_records = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).order_by(model.timestamp).all()
```

I realize that my `all_records` list can get very large so I will need to modify this to something like:

```
def get_most_recent(session, model, **kwargs):
    """ Get a single element from the DB which has the most recent timstemp """
    before_date = kwargs.pop('last_datetime', None)
    all_records = session.query(model).filter_by(**kwargs).order_by(model.timestamp).limit(1).all()
```

But how can I also add in the option of getting records *before* `before_date` (unless it is `None`)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just slap a filter on somewhere before `order_by`, like:

```py
def get_most_recent(session, model, before_date=None, **kwargs):
    """ Get a single row from the DB which has the most recent timestamp, before `before_date` """
    all_records = session.query(model).filter(
        model.timestamp < before_date (might require a cast or a different operator)
    ).filter_by(
        **kwargs
    ).order_by(
        model.timestamp
    ).first_or_none() # unless you really need a list, this might be simpler than .limit(1).all()

    return all_records
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! One nit: `first_or_none()` doesn't appear to be a thing; simply doing `first()` will return None if there are no records.

Comment: Also if the objective is to get the most recent timestamp (rather than the oldest), then they need to be sorted in descending order: `.order_by(model.timestamp.desc()).first()`